# Although I can generate the stubs with io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-kotlin I can't implement it

Tags: kotlin, gradle, grpc, micronaut, proto

Issue: I can't implement an object autogenerated from protobuf.

How reproduce: generated a project from micronaut initializer with: gRPC Application type, Java 11, Kotlin. Add io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-kotlin on build.gradle, build it, add a controller and try implement GrpcdemoServiceGrpcKt.

[image: Unresolved issue]

build.gradle

```
    plugins {
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm" version "1.4.10"
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt" version "1.4.10"
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.allopen" version "1.4.10"
    id "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow" version "6.1.0"
    id "io.micronaut.application" version '1.0.5'
    id "com.google.protobuf" version "0.8.13"
}

version "0.1"
group "com.mybank"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

micronaut {
    testRuntime "junit5"
    processing {
        incremental true
        annotations "com.mybank.*"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-validation")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:${kotlinVersion}")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:${kotlinVersion}")
    implementation("io.micronaut.kotlin:micronaut-kotlin-runtime")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-runtime")
    implementation("io.micronaut.grpc:micronaut-grpc-runtime")
    implementation("javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api")
    runtimeOnly("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic")
    runtimeOnly("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    testImplementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client")

    implementation("io.grpc:grpc-kotlin-stub:${grpcKotlinVersion}")
}

mainClassName = "com.mybank.ApplicationKt"
java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion('11')
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '11'
    }
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '11'
    }
}



sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs 'build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc'
            srcDirs 'build/generated/source/proto/main/java'
        }
    }
}

protobuf {
    protoc { artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.13.0" }
    plugins {
        grpc { artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.32.1" }
        grpckt { artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-kotlin:${grpcKotlinVersion}" }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all()*.plugins {
            grpc {}
            grpckt {}
        }
    }
}
```

gradle.properties

```
micronautVersion=2.1.3
kotlinVersion=1.4.10
grpcKotlinVersion=0.1.2
```

All the rest are exactly the same from micronaut.launch

Possible solution: there is an example I downloaded and started it successsfuly and called it from BloomRPC. It is from oficial examples [github](https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-grpc/tree/master/examples/hello-world-kotlin). Looking at it I see a much more complex gradle.

build gradle from Hello World

```
plugins {
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm" version "1.3.72"
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt" version "1.3.72"
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.allopen" version "1.3.72"
    id "application"
    id 'com.google.protobuf' version '0.8.13'
}

version "0.2"
group "helloworld"

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
}

configurations {
    // for dependencies that are needed for development only
    developmentOnly
}

dependencies {
    kapt(enforcedPlatform("io.micronaut:micronaut-bom:$micronautVersion"))
    kapt("io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-java")
    kapt("io.micronaut:micronaut-validation")

    implementation(enforcedPlatform("io.micronaut:micronaut-bom:$micronautVersion"))
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:${kotlinVersion}")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:${kotlinVersion}")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$kotlinxCoroutinesVersion")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-runtime")
//    implementation("io.micronaut.grpc:micronaut-grpc-runtime")
    implementation("io.micronaut.grpc:micronaut-grpc-server-runtime:$micronautGrpcVersion")
    implementation("io.micronaut.grpc:micronaut-grpc-client-runtime:$micronautGrpcVersion")
    implementation("io.grpc:grpc-kotlin-stub:${grpcKotlinVersion}")

    runtimeOnly("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3")
    runtimeOnly("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.9.8")

    kaptTest("io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-java")

    testImplementation enforcedPlatform("io.micronaut:micronaut-bom:$micronautVersion")
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.3.0")
    testImplementation("io.micronaut.test:micronaut-test-junit5")
    testImplementation("org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:2.22.0")

    testRuntime("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.3.0")
    testRuntime("org.jetbrains.spek:spek-junit-platform-engine:1.1.5")
}

test.classpath += configurations.developmentOnly

mainClassName = "helloworld.Application"

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

allOpen {
    annotation("io.micronaut.aop.Around")
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8' 
        //Will retain parameter names for Java reflection
        javaParameters = true 
    }
}
//compileKotlin.dependsOn(generateProto)

compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8' 
        javaParameters = true 
    }
}

tasks.withType(JavaExec) {
    classpath += configurations.developmentOnly
    jvmArgs('-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1', '-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote')
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs 'build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc'
            srcDirs 'build/generated/source/proto/main/grpckt'
            srcDirs 'build/generated/source/proto/main/java'
        }
    }
}

protobuf {
    protoc { artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:${protocVersion}" }
    plugins {
        grpc { artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:${grpcVersion}" }
        grpckt { artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-kotlin:${grpcKotlinVersion}" }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all()*.plugins {
            grpc {}
            grpckt {}
        }
    }
}
```

Question: what I am missing in order to implement the autogenerated stubs since it was generated? Do I need more gradle dependencies beyond io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-kotlin? I guess not. Am I in right direction? If not, what should I do in order to implement the send rpc method from demo project downloaded from Micronaut.launch?

PS.: when I tried the most recent version from io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-kotlin [0.2.1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.grpc/protoc-gen-grpc-kotlin/0.2.1) gradle complains so I just use 0.1.2 which is the same from official example. This is not an issue for me as long as it is not related to my problem.

Disclaimer: origonally asked in [micronaut github](https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-grpc/issues/257)

Comment: Your code should compile with command line right? It should just be the IDE not able to pick up the generated code.

Try add `srcDirs 'build/generated/source/proto/main/grpckt'` in your main sourceSet configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I had some issues with this one too.

I think that what you actually want to do is that you want to implement ImplBase that is generated and resided in your GrpcKt file and not the entire object itself

I've started an example here that you can follow:
https://github.com/FerhatBahceci/store-service/blob/master/build.gradle.kts

https://github.com/FerhatBahceci/store-service/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/store/service/store/StoreService.kt

Comment: Hi! That's a pretty good answer! Can you copy the most relevant code bits to your post here? You might someday want to move your repositories and the answer here will cease to be valid or useful. Keeping answers self-contained helps prevent that.

Comment: Hi there! You're absolutely right, I'm adding the build.gradle setup below.

Answer (score 1):

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile
import com.google.protobuf.gradle.*

group = "store.service"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

buildscript {

    dependencies {
        classpath(kotlin("gradle-plugin", version = "1.4.20"))
        classpath("com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.8.14")
        classpath("io.micronaut.gradle:micronaut-gradle-plugin:1.2.0")
    }
}

plugins {
    idea
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.4.20"
    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "1.4.20"
    id("com.google.protobuf") version "0.8.14"
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "6.1.0"
    id("io.micronaut.application") version "1.2.0"
}

micronaut {
    runtime("netty")
    testRuntime("junit5")
    processing {
        incremental(true)
        annotations("store.service.*")
    }
}

application {
    mainClass.set("store.service.App.java")
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion("1.8")
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion("1.8")
}


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {

/*
8 Generating a Micronaut Application's Native Image with GraalVM
    annotationProcessor("io.micronaut:micronaut-graal")
*/

    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-validation")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-runtime")
    implementation("io.micronaut.grpc:micronaut-grpc-server-runtime:2.2.0")
    implementation("io.micronaut.mongodb:micronaut-mongo-reactive:3.1.0")

    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-reactor:1.4.2")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.4.2")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-protobuf:1.0.1")

    implementation("io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-lite:1.33.1")
    implementation("io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:1.33.1")
    implementation("io.grpc:grpc-kotlin-stub-lite:0.2.1")
    implementation("io.grpc:grpc-netty:1.33.1")
    implementation("com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.14.0")
    implementation("com.google.guava:guava:30.0-jre")

    implementation("javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2")
    implementation("org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:2.0.0-alpha1")

    testImplementation("io.kotest:kotest-runner-junit5-jvm:4.2.5")
}

tasks {

    withType<KotlinCompile> {
        kotlinOptions {
            freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
            jvmTarget = "11"
        }
    }

    withType<Test> {
        useJUnitPlatform()
    }
}

protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.11.4"
    }
    plugins {
        id("grpc") {
            artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.25.0"
        }
        id("grpckt") {
            artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-kotlin:0.2.0:jdk7@jar"
        }
    }

    generateProtoTasks {
        ofSourceSet("main").forEach {
            it.plugins {
                id("grpc")
                id("grpckt")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In your GrpcdemoServiceGrpcK, you'll find your ImplBase. Implement a concrete grpc service from this ImplBase.